# Multi-language website approach with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm using simple object arrays to store my data for the website. For example:

```
const aboutContent = {
heading: "hello",
message: "welcome to the website"
};
```

or

```
const contactContent = [
{
name: "John Doe",
title: "Fullstack Dev",
mail: "john@asdasd.com"
},{
name: "Jane Doe",
title: "UX Designer",
mail: "jane@asdasd.com"
},
];
```

I'm planning to make another language version for the website and I'm wondering what is the best approach. I consider using Router and creating another level of it. Also I will have to create {aboutContent} and {contactContent} in the other language, but how do I manage to switch between the two. How to dynamically read the data based on chosen language?

Comment: I would enchance the object as such: `const aboutContent = [ en: {}, fr: {} ... ]`

Comment: Oh, that's cool! But how do I manage to load the correct data? On what condition should I do this?

Comment: I suppose you will have a state for the current site language so you can call it in the code like this:
`{aboutContent[siteLang].heading}`